# Если в where условие тру, исключить эту строку из результирующей таблицы. Как?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

```
select p.id from provider as p
join application a on p.id = a.provider_id
where a.created_at between current_date - interval '90 day' and 
current_date
```

как получить только тех провайдеров, у которых нет ни одного апликейшена, созданного за последние 90 дней?

UPD

Если перед between поставить not, в результирующий набор попадают провайдеры у который есть апликейшены не в ходящие в этот диапазон, но это не гарантирует нам что там не будет апликейшенов и в этом диапазоне

Comment: поменять на false? ) Поставьте NOT перед between

Comment: @AK Если перед between поставить not, в результирующий набор попадают провайдеры у который есть апликейшены не в ходящие в этот диапазон, но это не гарантирует нам что там не будет апликейшенов и в этом диапазоне

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select p.id
from provider as p
where not exists (select 1 from application a where p.id = a.provider_id and a.created_at between current_date - interval '90 day' and 
current_date)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: не забудь посмотреть план запроса и, при необходимости, построить индекс

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно обратить условие, например используя оператор `NOT`. Либо изменить содержание условия, что должно быть эквивалентно.

Comment: Если перед between поставить not, в результирующий набор попадают провайдеры у который есть апликейшены не в ходящие в этот диапазон, но это не гарантирует нам что там не будет апликейшенов и в этом диапазоне

Comment: Как раз гарантирует https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html

Comment: не гарантирует. если у провайдера есть два апликейшена, один из которых попадает в диапазон, второй не попадает, то что предлагаете Вы, вернет этого провайдера, а это не верно по условию задачи

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from provider where id not in (
select p.id from provider as p
join application a on p.id = a.provider_id
where a.created_at between current_date - interval '90 day' and 
current_date)
```